# How do I write a script to output an html file?

Tags: html, bash, shell

I have a very simple bash script. I want to output the result of running the script to the html. However, html, "$ {ec_1} $ {ec_2}" was so.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << 'EOF' > 01.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Convert</title>
    </head>
    <body>
EOF

ec_1="====Default ID===="
if [ `cat /etc/passwd | egrep "lp:|uucp:|nuccp:" | wc -l` -eq 0 ] ; then
echo /etc/passwd | egrep "lp:|uucp:|nuccp:" > $ec_2
fi

cat << 'EOF' >> 01.html
<h1>${ec_1}</h1>
<h5>${ec_2}</h5>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

[result 01.html]

${ec_1}

${ec_2}

Comment: Why not use `echo "<h1>${ec_1}</h1>" >> 01.html`, etc?

Comment: I want the value in the table.

Comment: So arrange your `echo` commands to make that happen. Your question doesn't make it clear how you want your table to be setup. You're using header tags inside a table body but aren't outputting any `tr` or `td` tags. Are you familiar with HTML tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes (to large for an comment)

Your code:

```
if [ `cat /etc/passwd | egrep "lp:|uucp:|nuccp:" | wc -l` -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo /etc/passwd | egrep "lp:|uucp:|nuccp:" > $ec_2
fi
```

Here you proof the number of output lines of `egrep`. If it produce no lines, you extract these 0 lines. I think, you mean `-gt 0`.

Then you wrote `echo /etc/passwd`. I think, `cat /etc/passwd` is correct, or `egrep ... /etc/passwd`.

Anyway, the if-condition is not necessary at all, just do:

```
egrep "lp:|uucp:|nuccp:" /etc/password > $ec_2
```

Otherwise, `$ec_2` is undefined (no alternative if `if ...` is false.

`>$ec_2` writes a file, and not a variable. Later you access undefined variable `$ec_2`.

Comment: finally, the `<< 'EOF'` needs to be `<< "EOF"` for the variables to be expanded